# Use of Distinct & Order by in Sql Server 2008

Tags: sql-server, distinct

I wan to use distinct in a join query with order by. Distinct column and order by columns are different.

Answer (score 3):

SQL Server only allows you to `ORDER BY` columns in the `SELECT` list when `DISTINCT` is specified as otherwise the non selected column might have more than one value mapping to a particular row in the returned results.

If you know for a fact this is not the case you can use a CTE.

```
;WITH CTE
     AS (SELECT DISTINCT foo,
                         bar
         FROM   T)
SELECT foo
FROM   CTE
ORDER  BY bar
```

If this doesn't work for you because there are actually multiple possible `bar` values for each `foo` then you need to tell it unambiguously which value to use for ordering purposes. e.g. by using `GROUP BY` instead.

```
SELECT foo
FROM T
GROUP BY foo
ORDER BY MIN(bar)
```

Comment: +1 that's a nice workaround!  I'm going to remember that one.